# when is it suitable to use of `are to be +pp` structure?

Tags: passive-voice

I saw this sentence, and I am wondering what is its structure and its purpose

```
elements are to be displayed on screen
```

what is the structure, what is the meaning?

Comment: Do you know what the context is? Is it a command, or is it just giving information?

Comment: [It's an idiomatic construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/93462/15299). The core of the idiom is _be to_ + `VP`, where `VP` is an infinitive (basic form, untensed, unmarked) verb phrase. The _be_ + `pp` at the end in the question is not part of the idiom.

Comment: @BillJ that is giving information.`CSS describes how HTML elements are to be displayed on screen, paper, or in other media`

Answer (score 1):

> *Elements are to be displayed on screen*

This involves a special “quasi-modal” use of “be”, where it has a passive interpretation and strong deontic modality similar to “must”, as in “elements must be displayed on screen”.

Comment: can you give me any link for more information?

Comment: @Alireza There are some resources on the Internet. Here's one I found. It's pretty heavy but worth a skim:[link](https://nicholeoberheu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Quasi-modals-and-Grammaticalization-What-TESOL-Professional-Ought-to-Know1.pdf)